# How do you validate multiple items?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

How do you validate multiple items in JavaScript, but without nesting ifs?

**Not this...**

```
if ( username && username.length > 2 && username.length < 45 ) {
  if ( password && password.length ... ) {
    if ( birthday && birthday.isNumeric ...) {
      if ( age && ... && ...) {
        // Success
      } else {
        // Error 4
      }
    } else {
      // Error 3     
    }
  } else {
    // Error 2
  }
} else {
  // Error 1
}
```

**...rather, this...**

```
validate({

  validate 'username' and use these conditions 'username && username.length...',
  validate 'password' and use these conditions 'password && password.length...',
  validate 'birthday' and use these conditions 'birthday && birthday.isNumeric...',
  validate 'age' and use these conditions 'age && ... && ...'

}, function(error) {

  if ( !error ) {
    // Success
  }

});
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks for reply!

Comment: Those are nested `if` statements, not objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), which will be much easier and more effective than duplicating it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle things like this like so:

```
var error = new Array();
var errorNum = 0;

if(!(username && username.length > 2 && ...)) {
    error[errorNum++] = "ERROR1";
}

if(!(password &&...)) {
  error[errorNum++] = "ERROR2";
}
```

No nesting required.

Edit: Sorry, initial syntax as PhP not javascript.  I mix the two too often sometimes.

Comment: It's still invalid: it's `Array`, and I would rather use `var error = [];` and [`error.push("ERRORx")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: @Marcel Fixed... again.  Sorry, it's a general pattern that I was trying to share more than specific syntax.  I usually use it in PhP, so that's the syntax that came out of my head when I went to share it.